# Symfony 2 & Doctrine 2: Complicated relation beetwen entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have two entities. First called "Status":

```
<?php
class Status {
    protected $id;
    protected $type = null; // standarized type of status (f.e. "locked", "disabled")
    protected $value = true; // true or false (value of status)
    protected $change_reason = null;
    protected $changed_by;
    protected $changed_at;
}
```

I've cleared annotations for better readability.

And the second called eg. Account. Because Account is not the only one entity using Statuses, relations beetwen Status and any other "statusable" entity (I think) should be many-to-many. For Account there would be join table account_status etc.

Additionaly one status belongs to only one Entity.

It all works in that configuration, but I really don't know how to retrieve a list of accounts with their latest statuses.

I wrote an SQL query to retrieve actual statuses:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.type, t.value
    FROM status AS t
    ORDER BY t.changed_at DESC
) AS t1 GROUP BY t1.type
```

My questions are:

1. Is that idea correct at all?
2. How to retrieve a list of accounts with all their latest statuses?

Sorry for my poor English.

**EDIT**:
I want just to get an account, join its latest statuses, and then get them simply by: $task -> getStatus('highlighted') to get a value of a latest (youngest) status of type "highlighted"

**EDIT2**:
ideal would be still have ability to sort and filter by status of given type

Comment: You can add lastStatus relation to each account

Comment: each account can have more than one status, eg. "locked", "expired" and so on... Better example for this would be a Task - "closed", "highlighted".

Answer (score 1):

```php
class Task {

    // this is list of all statuses
    protected $statusHistory;

    protected $lastStatus;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->statusHistory = new Arraycollection();
    }

    public function addStatus($status) {
        $this->statusHistory[] = $status;
        $this->lastStatus = $status;
    }

    public function getStatusHistory() {
        return $this->statusHistory;
    }

    public function getLastStatus() {
        return $this->lastStatus;
    }
}

// to get list of statuses
$task->getStatusHistory();

// to get last status, it returns Status object, not collection
$task->getLastStatus();
```

It's more or less standard approach when you need first/last element from collection and getting the whole collection might be an overhead.

Comment: That's not what I needed. I want just to get a account, join its latest statuses, and then get them simply by:
    $task -> getStatus('highlighted')
to get a value of a latest status of type "highlighted".